# Rmarkdown plotly figures side by side

Tags: r, plotly, r-markdown

I want two [plotly](/questions/tagged/plotly) figures to appear side by side using [r-markdown](/questions/tagged/r-markdown).

````
```{r}
library(plotly)
```

```{r, figures-side, fig.show="hold", out.width="50%"}
plot_ly(x = iris$Species, y = iris$Sepal.Length, type = "bar")
plot_ly(x = iris$Species, y = iris$Petal.Length, type = "bar")
```
````

When I knit this, the figures appear on different lines. How can I make them side by side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `manipulateWidget::combineWidgets`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
date: "2022-12-02"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(plotly)
```

```{r, fig.show="hold"}
ply1 <- plot_ly(x = iris$Species, y = iris$Sepal.Length, type = "bar")
ply2 <- plot_ly(x = iris$Species, y = iris$Petal.Length, type = "bar")
manipulateWidget::combineWidgets(ply1, ply2, nrow = 1)
```
````

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to not rely on markdown to plot the figures side by side but do it explicitly via `plotly`. Here's an option with `subplot` function.

```
library(plotly)
plotly::subplot(plot_ly(x = iris$Species, y = iris$Sepal.Length, type = "bar"),
                plot_ly(x = iris$Species, y = iris$Petal.Length, type = "bar"), 
                nrows = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: I would prefer a solution using rmarkdown because I like the appearance more. I will vote for this if an rmarkdown solution is not proposed.